# SwiftUI - Can't fill screen on the bottom of sheet

Tags: swiftui

The bottom of my sheet is not filling up with color for some reason. Tried the below code, but can only fill the top safe space. Any clue?

[image: Sheet not filling up with color]

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            Text("Hi")
                .font(.title)
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(hex: 0x71A2B6), Color(hex: 0xF09D51)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` down to cover the `GeometryRender` so that it would fill the device, thus providing the correct screen dimensions.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            Text("Hi")
                .font(.title)
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width,
               height: geometry.size.height)
        .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]),
                                   startPoint: .top,
                                   endPoint: .bottom))

    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have set `.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)` which will not cover the bottom area.

And if your goal is just to have your View fill the whole screen you may not need a `GeometryReader`.

You can try using a `ZStack` instead:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(hex: 0x71A2B6), Color(hex: 0xF09D51)]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            VStack {
                Text("Hi")
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Xcode 15, iOS 17**

Instead of using `GeometryReader` and the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` modifier separate, you can now use it within your `.background` modifier`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Background Me!")
    }
    .background(.red, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: .bottom)
  }
}
```

This will ignore the bottom safe area.